# numpy returns 1d array and 2d array for same code

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am not really aware of what rules does numpy follows when performing some 2d array operations with regards to returning the result as a 1d or 2d array. Let us consider the following piece of code

```
idx_cls_samples = sample_data[:, -1] == c
v_feature = sample_data[idx_cls_samples, f]

f_values = sample_data[[sample_data[:, -1] == c], f]
```

Note that the last line is simply the first two lines combined into one.

The result of first two lines is a numpy vector of the form array([1, 2, 3, ...]) and the result of last line is array([[1, 2, 3, ...]]) and I believe the result should have been array([1], [2], [3], ...]) in both cases. How can I figure out beforehand what format will numpy choose to return the result?

Comment: the last line is not quite the same, `sample_data[sample_data[:, -1] == c, f]` would be the same (dropped an extra set of brackets)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note that the last line is simply the first two lines combined into one.

No it's not. You stuck an extra pair of brackets in there:

```
f_values = sample_data[[sample_data[:, -1] == c], f]
#                      ^                       ^
```

Take them out.

As for the indexing rules, those are in the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html). They're pretty long.

Answer (score 0):

`sample_data` is 2d.  `sample_data[:,-1]` is 1d, the last column.  Indexing with a scalar removes a dimension.

The `...=c` produces a boolean of the same dimension (1d).

`sample_data[:, f]` is also a 1d, the `fth` column.

Indexing that with a boolean array returns a result of the same dimension of the boolean, but just a subset of the values

`sample_data[idx, f]` is 1d, `sample_data[[idx], f]` is 2d (due to the added `[]`).

You probably wanted, `sample_data[(sample_data[:, -1] == c), f]`, where `()` just groups the strings, sometimes for operator precedence, sometimes just to make more readable.  (but beware of `(...,)`, which makes a tuple).

`sample_data[idx, [f]]` would have given you the column 'vector', 2d with 1 column.

Another way to look at `sample_data[idx,f]` is: `idx` selects a subset of rows, `f` selects a column from that 2d.

Often 2d (or higher nd) indexing can be studied axis by axis; that's especially true with an index is scalar, or a slice.  It's more complicated if an index is a list or array, or worse, 2 or more of those.